# AggregateResults Grouping of Picklist to String Error

Tags: apex

I'm attempting to summarize invoice data by type of invoice grouped by time period.  Income_Class__c is a picklist field and upon running this code I get an error: Invalid conversion from runtime type integer to string.

1 - What do I need to modify here to get the correct Income_Class__c picklist value to display?

2 - When this runs I get more results than desired.  Any idea how I can make this only create records grouped by Income Class and Month (but also display the calendar year?).

```
AggregateResult[] RevDataMonth = [SELECT GROUPING(Income_Class__c)         IncomeGroup, CALENDAR_MONTH(Transaction_Date__c) CalMonth, 
                                CALENDAR_YEAR(Transaction_Date__c) CalYear, SUM(Net_Revenue__c) SumRev
                                FROM Invoice__c
                                WHERE Company__c = '001Q000000VDkpq'
                                GROUP BY ROLLUP(Income_Class__c, CALENDAR_MONTH(Transaction_Date__c), CALENDAR_YEAR(Transaction_Date__c))];
{
for (AggregateResult a : RevDataMonth){
        RevRollupAug12__c r = new RevRollupAug12__c();
        r.month__c = (Integer)a.get('CalMonth');
        r.year__c = (Integer)a.get('CalYear');
        r.Amount__c = (Decimal)a.get('SumRev');
        r.company__c = '001Q000000VDkpq'; 
        r.Time_Period__c = 'Month';
        r.Income_Class__c = (String)a.getvalue('IncomeGroup');
        insert r; }}}
```

Comment: I found this blog post helpful - http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/04/12/using-aggregateresult-in-salesforce-com-soql/ - Given the 10k limit when querying records this is not as useful as I originally thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [GROUPING()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_grouping.htm) function is used to identify subtotal rows - it identifies subtotal rows in a result set, and returns 1 if the row is a subtotal for the field, and 0 otherwise - it doesn't yield the field value itself.

If you want the sum of the revenue for each combination of calendar month, year and income class, I think the SOQL query is a bit simpler:

```
AggregateResult[] RevDataMonth = 
   [SELECT CALENDAR_MONTH(Transaction_Date__c) CalMonth, 
        CALENDAR_YEAR(Transaction_Date__c) CalYear, 
        SUM(Net_Revenue__c) SumRev, Income_Class__c 
    FROM Invoice__c 
    WHERE Company__c = '001Q000000VDkpq'
    GROUP BY CALENDAR_MONTH(Transaction_Date__c), 
        CALENDAR_YEAR(Transaction_Date__c), Income_Class__c];
for (AggregateResult a : RevDataMonth) {
    RevRollupAug12__c r = new RevRollupAug12__c();
    r.month__c = (Integer)a.get('CalMonth');
    r.year__c = (Integer)a.get('CalYear');
    r.Amount__c = (Decimal)a.get('SumRev');
    r.company__c = '001Q000000VDkpq'; 
    r.Time_Period__c = 'Month';
    r.Income_Class__c = (String)a.get('Income_Class__c');
    insert r; 
}
```

Comment: @MMcNamara : if this solved your question please accept the answer so others know you've been helped. ( you can do this by clicking the (V) icon to the left of metadaddy's answer.)

Comment: Done - thx for the tip

Answer (score 0):

I don't  think you can do a simple casting from a numeric type to String. Have you tried this:

r.Income_Class__c = String.valueOf(a.getvalue('IncomeGroup'));

Comment: No luck - "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [SOBJECT:AggregateResult].getvalue(String)"

Comment: My bad. r.Income_Class__c = String.valueOf(a.get('IncomeGroup'));